# Unable to use returned JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I've got a simple bit of code in PHP that queries, grabs the resulting array, and echoes it so I can pick it up in javascript:

```
echo json_encode($emailQuery->result);
```

(the ->result part is Expression Engine; it returns an array of the result set)

My javascript to receive the code is as follows:

```
$.post("/dev/onboardingEmailsSubmit", loadInfo, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I output data, it outputs the entire string as I would expect, ie. {[varname:"value", etc.]}.  But data['varName'], it is undefined.  data.varName is also undefined.  data[0] is the first character of the JSON string, leading me to believe that javascript is not at all using this as an object.  data[1] is the 2nd character, etc.

Does anyone know what's going on here?  I need to be working with an array of data.

Comment: If your php script outputs `header('Content-type: application/json');`, jquery should pick up that automatically and decide it for you. Otherwise, it's probably going out as text/html or text/plain.

Comment: Thanks @Marc B, I'll have to try this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you have not parsed the JSON. How should the browser or jQuery know that the response you get is JSON? (also see @Marc's comment)

You can pass `'json'` as fourth parameter to [`$.post` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to let jQuery parse the response for you.

Comment: You can also use `$.parseJSON( response )` per http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I guess I thought that javascript is supposed to read the text and act accordingly.  Thanks.  However, my attempts at calling data[0] work fine, but data[0].varName do not work at all.  I've looked at a number of guides, and they all tell me to use data[0].body (in my case).  I've also tried data[0]['body'].

Comment: @Paragon: Although the JSON syntax is similar to JavaScript's object literal syntax, JSON has no special meaning for JavaScript. It is a data format like any other, e.g. XML. *Edit:* You can only access properties that exist, but you did not post an example of the structure, so I cannot help you here.

Comment: @Felix Kling, you're right.  Thanks for focusing my search: it was a structure issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("/dev/onboardingEmailsSubmit", loadInfo, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

jQuery will parse the JSON, if you pass `'json'` as 4th param to `$.post`.